# How to add up specific hash attributes within an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, addition, inject

I want to add up specific attributes from an array of hashes... here's an example array:

```
@horses = [
        {name: "Runner1", odds: 4.00},
        {name: "Runner2", odds: 20.00},
        {name: "Runner3", odds: 4.00}
        ]
```

And am trying this method:

```
@total_odds = horses[:odds].inject(:+)
```

But I'm getting an error: `[ ]': can't convert Symbol into Integer`

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance (have just started learning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@horses.collect {|h| h[:odds] }.inject(:+)
```

Comment: Fixed. Many thanks... will mark as answered in a few minutes when it lets me.

Comment: Might be nice to also elaborate on why the OP's attempt doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a block with [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) if you need to unpack the elements that you're iterating over:

```
@horses.inject(0) { |m, h| m + h[:odds] }
```

When you say this:

```
@total_odds = horses[:odds].inject(:+)
```

You're trying to use a symbol, `:odds`, as an index for an Array; Array indexes are integers and there's no way for an Array to convert a symbol to an integer so you get an `can't convert Symbol into Integer` error.